# Ajax post request only gets through once browser is closed and opened again

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have been working with AJAX, JQuery, and Sessions for a very long time. But this is the first time that I have encountered this problem.

I am sending a normal post request to another page and like my old codes, I use sessions in the target page to test if my AJAX request was successful.

For all those times that I have done this it worked perfectly, except of course when there are some obvious Javascript errors preventing my AJAX to proceed successfully.

Now what happen is that for the ajax request to be successful I need to trigger it after I close and re open my browser, If I were to do it again after sending the first request it will not proceed successfully anymore, another funny thing is that I always get an error when I enable the error response for AJAX, Which is really bothersome and annoying since I just cant identify the root cause of this problem.

Is this a server problem or code problem or some rule I don't know about?

My Code excluding the included the JS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .input-select { width: 200px; } 
    .bordered-table { border-collapse:collapse; margin:5px; }
    .bordered-table td { border:1px solid #ccc; padding:4px; }
</style>
<link href="/admin/shop/css/tabs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {    

    $(".tab_content").hide();
     $("ul.tabs").each(function () {
         $(this).find('li:first').addClass("current");
         $(this).next('.panes').find('.tab_content:first').show();
     });

    /* binding click to display another tab */
    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function(event) {

        var cTab = $(this).closest('li');
         cTab.siblings('li').removeClass("current");
         cTab.addClass("current");
         cTab.closest('ul.tabs').nextAll('.panes:first').find('.tab_content').hide();

         var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
         $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
         return false;
    });



});
    function checkIt(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            status = "This field accepts numbers only."
            return false
        }
        status = ""
        return true
    }

    function addRows(elem) {
        var ctr = parseInt($("#rows_ctr").val())+parseInt(1);
        var row = $(elem);
        emails_dropdown = $("#email_id_sample").clone();
        row.closest('.adder').parents(".adder-row").before('<tr><td><b>Subject</b>:</td><td><select name="email_id[]" id="email_id_'+ctr+'" style="width: 350px;margin-right: 5;">'+emails_dropdown.html()+'</select></td></tr>');
        $("#rows_ctr").val(ctr);
        // $("#email_id_"+ctr).val('');
    }

    function addForm() {
        var ctr = parseInt($("#rows_ctr1").val())+parseInt(1);
        form_content = $("#formcopy").clone();
        $('#cform > tbody > tr:last').after('<tr><td><div id="crm-feedback'+ctr+'"></div><form id="form'+ctr+'" onsubmit="return setList('+ctr+');">'+form_content.html()+'<form/></td></tr>');
        $("#rows_ctr1").val(ctr);
    }

    function setList(str){
        var postDatas = decodeURI($('#form'+str+'').serialize());
        console.log('Post data: ' + postDatas);
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url+"admin/page/file.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: postDatas,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#crm-feedback'+str+'').html('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"></center>');
             },
            success: function(data){
                // $('#crm-feedback').html('Saved!').css('color','green');
                console.log('Success');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<body class="colorbox-body">
    <div class="welcome-box">
        <h1>Set Group Email and SMS</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colorbox-content">
        <div id="notification">
            <?php 
                if($email_success){ 
                        echo"<font style='color:green;'>Schedule Saved.</font>";
                        echo '<script>
                                    setTimeout("$(\"#notification\").fadeOut()",5000);
                                </script>';
                }   
                if($nochanges==1){
                    echo "<font style='color:red;'>No changes made.</font>";
                    echo '<script>
                                    setTimeout("$(\"#notification\").fadeOut()",5000);
                            </script>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <h2>Set Group Email and SMS</h2>
        <table id="cform">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <form id = "form0" name="form0" onsubmit="return setList(0);">                    
                    <div class="sel">
                    <?php
                        $ctr = 0;
                        //get group emails
                        $sql_grpemails = "some things";
                        $res_grpemails = mysql_query($sql_grpemails);
                        if(mysql_num_rows($res_grpemails) > 0) {
                            while($row_grpemails = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_grpemails)) {
                                echo '<tr><td><b>Subject:</b></td>';
                                echo '<td><select name="email_id[]" id="email_id_'.$ctr.'" style="width: 350px;margin-right: 5;">
                                                <optgroup label="Emails">
                                                <option value="">-- Select --</option>';
                                                    $res_savedemails = mysql_query($sql_savedemails);
                                                    while($row_savedemails = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedemails)) {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedemails['sam_msg_id'].'" '.($row_savedemails['sam_msg_id']==$row_grpemails['email_id']?'selected':'').'>'.$row_savedemails['sam_subject'].'(Email)</option>';
                                                    }
                                echo '                  
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SMS">';
                                                    $res_savedsms = mysql_query($sql_savedsms);
                                                    while($row_savedsms = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedsms)) {
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedsms['id'].'-sms" '.($row_savedsms['id']==$row_grpemails['email_id']?'selected':'').'>'.$row_savedsms['subject'].'(SMS)</option>';
                                                    }
                                echo '
                                            </optgroup>
                                            </select></td></tr>';
                                $ctr++;
                            }
                        } 
                    ?>
                    <table cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b>Subject:</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="email_id[]" id="email_id_<?php echo $ctr;?>" style="width: 350px;margin-right: 5;">
                                    <optgroup label="Emails">
                                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                    <?php
                                        $res_savedemails = mysql_query($sql_savedemails);
                                        while($row_savedemails = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedemails)) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row_savedemails['sam_msg_id'].'">'.$row_savedemails['sam_subject'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="SMS">
                                    <?php
                                        $res_savedsms = mysql_query($sql_savedsms);
                                        while($row_savedsms = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedsms)) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row_savedsms['id'].'-sms">'.$row_savedsms['subject'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr class="adder-row">
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="button" class="adder btn-link right" value="Add More" onclick="addRows(this);" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>                                  
                        </table>

                    </div>                                                             
                        <br/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="rows_ctr" id="rows_ctr" value="<?php echo $ctr;?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="rows_ctr1" id="rows_ctr1" value="<?php echo $ctr;?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="gid" id="" value="<?php echo $_GET['gid'];?>" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-link right"  />
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>        
        </table>

        <table width="95%">         
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="button" class="btn-link right" value="Add More" onclick="javascript:addForm();" />     
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <select name="email_id_sample" id="email_id_sample" style="display:none;">
                <optgroup label="Emails">
                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                <?php
                    $res_savedemails = mysql_query($sql_savedemails);
                    while($row_savedemails = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedemails)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedemails['sam_msg_id'].'">'.$row_savedemails['sam_subject'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="SMS">
                <?php
                    $res_savedsms = mysql_query($sql_savedsms);
                    while($row_savedsms = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedsms)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedsms['id'].'-sms">'.$row_savedsms['subject'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </optgroup>
        </select>

        <form id = "formcopy" name="form1" method="post" action="" style="display:none">

                <table cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Subject:</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="email_id[]" id="email_id_<?php echo $ctr;?>" style="width: 350px;margin-right: 5;">
                                <optgroup label="Emails">
                                <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                                <?php
                                    $res_savedemails = mysql_query($sql_savedemails);
                                    while($row_savedemails = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedemails)) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedemails['sam_msg_id'].'">'.$row_savedemails['sam_subject'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </optgroup>
                                <optgroup label="SMS">
                                <?php
                                    $res_savedsms = mysql_query($sql_savedsms);
                                    while($row_savedsms = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_savedsms)) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_savedsms['id'].'-sms">'.$row_savedsms['subject'].'</option>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="adder-row">
                        <td colspan="2">                                                
                           <input type="button" class="adder btn-link right" value="Add More" onclick="addRows(this);" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                                                     
            <div class="scheduled_days">
                <p><b>Scheduled (Days)</b></p>
                <br/>
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab5">Days</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab6">Weekly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab7">Monthly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab8">Yearly</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="panes">
                    <div id="tab5" class="tab_content" style = "padding-top: 20px;">
                        <b>Recurring:</b> Every&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="dval"/> Day(s)
                        <br/>
                        <small>*Reference date: Member date added to the group</small>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab6" class="tab_content" style = "padding-top: 20px;">
                        <b>Recurring:</b> Every&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="wval"/> Week(s)
                        <br/>
                        <small>*Reference date: Member date added to the group</small>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weekmon"/> Monday <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weektue"/>Tuesday <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weekwed"/>Wednesday <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weekthu"/>Thursday <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weekfri"/> Friday
                        <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weeksat"/> Saturday <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="weeksun"/> Sunday
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab7" class="tab_content" style = "padding-top: 20px;">
                        <b>Recurring:</b> <br/><small>*Reference date: Member date added to the group</small>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="monthlyrecur"/> Day <input type="text" name="mday"/> of every <input type="text" name="mmonth"/> month(s)
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio"name="recursched" value="monthlyrecur"/> The 
                        <select name="mweek" class="styled">
                        <option value="First">First</option>
                        <option value="Second">Second</option>
                        <option value="Third">Third</option>
                        <option value="Fourth">Fourth</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab8" class="tab_content" style = "padding-top: 20px;">
                        <b>Recurring:</b> <br/><small>*Reference date: Member date added to the group</small>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="yearlyrecur"/> Every 
                        <select name="ymonth" class="styled">
                            <?php
                                $ymontshar = array("January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
                                for($ymonths=0;$ymonths<12;$ymonths++){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $ymontshar[$ymonths]; ?>"><?php echo $ymontshar[$ymonths]; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" name="yday"/>
                        <br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="recursched" value="yearlyrecur2"/> The
                        <select name="yweek" class="styled">
                            <option value="first">First</option>
                            <option value="second">Second</option>
                            <option value="third">Third</option>
                            <option value="fourth">Fourth</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="yday" class="styled">
                            <option value="monday">Monday</option>
                            <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                            <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
                            <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
                            <option value="friday">Friday</option>
                            <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
                            <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
                        </select>
                        of
                        <select name="ymonth2" class="styled">
                            <?php
                                for($ymonths2=0;$ymonths2<12;$ymonths2++){
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $ymontshar[$ymonths2]; ?>"><?php echo $ymontshar[$ymonths2]; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="rows_ctr" id="rows_ctr" value="<?php echo $ctr;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rows_ctr1" id="rows_ctr1" value="<?php echo $ctr;?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="gid" id="" value="<?php echo $_GET['gid'];?>" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn-link right"  />
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br />
        <div class="warning-msg">
            <b>*Please note that changing the schedule may result in some members not receiving emails.</b>
        </div>
    </div>        
</body>
```

**It now works on chrome, but not on all occasion, i might need to submit it twice before it gets trough**

Comment: what's the error message, then? we can't help identifying the root cause if you don't tell us any useful details.

Comment: @MarcB by that i mean that i added the error:function(){ event of the $.ajax. also there are no errors in my console

Comment: if the `error:` handler gets invoked, then there IS an error. try `error: function(xhr, message, error) { alert(message); }` to see what jquery's complaining about.

Comment: @MarcB will do, but why is that even though it gets invoked why does it still proceed to the target page?

Comment: @MarcB it just says error

Comment: Is this problem on only a specific browser, or on all browsers? Have you thrown a console.log into the setList function to make sure it's actually getting called when you think it is?

Comment: One wild hypothesis: elsewhere on the page, you're sending multiple AJAX requests off to some URL that never actually returns, and you're hitting the browser's limit on simultaneous AJAX requests, preventing the one in `setList` from ever actually being sent. Possible, but unlikely; you really need to *do some more investigative work of your own* so that you can *give us more information*.

Comment: @MarkAmery on all browsers, actually i really did do some investigating hence i was able to determine that it wont send unless i reopen the browser, also no errors on the console log, jquery error function just says error which is not very helpful. though one of my js function would not also work as expected i did a post about it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407252/jquery-multiple-tag-groups-in-one-page. maybe they are somehow related?

Comment: The AJAX error option has 3 parameters, which one returns error? If you try 'error: function(x, t, m)' and alert 'm' what does it say?

Comment: @KirKill tried error: function(xhr, message, error) { alert(message); } and it just says error, but though the request went trough. this is very confusing.

Comment: @magicianIam You alerted the wrong thing, the second parameter is the status, it can be error, timeout, abort or parseerror but it is only the status, what you need to alert is the third parameter, which would be "error" in your case, which is the error that is thrown.

Comment: Is the query in the Network tab (in the console window) fails or succeed? What is the status of the query? What are its headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there is an error in server side. You can identify that error by using ajax error handler, also try to use console.log() instead of alert() when debugging JS:

```
function setList(str){
    var postDatas = decodeURI($('#form'+str+'').serialize());
    console.log('Post data: ' + postDatas);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"admin/page/file.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: postDatas,
        success: function (data) {
            // $('#crm-feedback').html('Saved!').css('color','green');
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Then check the console for the detail message, I guess you would know what happened then.

Comment: this is what I got.
Post data: email_id[]=3-sms&dval=123&wval=&mday=&mmonth=&mweek=First&ymonth=January&yday=&yweek=first&yday=monday&ymonth2=January&rows_ctr=0&rows_ctr1=0&gid=47 setGroupEmail.php?gid=47:205
[object Object] setGroupEmail.php?gid=47:219
error

Comment: The post data looks normal. I guess there is an error when file setGroupEmail.php processes that request. You can click on the [object Object] to check if there is any detail on the error thrown. But well my guess is still server side fault.

Comment: what could cause this on the servers side?

Comment: It depends, all sort of error can cause this . You can get the error status code (500, 405, 403 ...) in network tab in chrome dev tools / firebug when doing the request. Anyway debugging server side code is a whole another story. Do you have access to server side at all?

Comment: yeah i have, what do i need to check there then? also updated the code. though i excluded the external JS files.

Comment: If you are sure the second, third, etc, `POST` request is making it to the server (it will show up in your http logs), check for php errors. Take a look at the `error_log` file if it is specified in the `php.ini` or set the `error_log` through `ini_set()` in your code.  `error_reporting` should be set to something verbose while developing `E_ALL && E_STRICT`. If all else fails, in your function go line by line adding die('got here')s until you start seeing the same (error) result. However, the browser itself might be the culprit.

Comment: Copying the php code here might be another way to go. Someone might notice the error pretty fast just by looking at the code. But in general you can follow above comment or set "break points" (echo '1'; echo '2'; etc in different sections) in the code to debug which section has the bug.

Comment: @HieuNguyen the request gets trough randomly now, though it wont work on firefox at all

Comment: The code works on Chrome only sounds like a JS issue. Is the request sent correctly in Firefox or it isn't sent at all (check Firebug's Network tab)?
One small question is is there any reason why you have to decodeURI() the serialized postdata? It doesn't seem to do anything there and it's perfectly normal to send the serialized data alone.

Answer (score 2):

Besides looking at the javascript console, you need to look at the actual traffic being exchanged.

Use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to check it out.

You should also try debugging the js with the tools available on the browser you use.

This is a key step to get it solved. You need to know for sure if the requests are really taking place. If those are, then you need to look at the difference in the requests. Otherwise you can debug the js to find out exactly what's going on.

Comment: do you have some specific list for chrome browser tools? thank you. the request gets trough though when the browser is recently opened even though the jquery gives me an error

Comment: used firefox addon instead called live http headers. on the first request i was able to 
GET /admin/setGroupEmail.php?email_id%5B%5D=&email_id%5B%5D=&dval=&wval=&mday=&mmonth=&mweek=First&ymonth=January&yday=&yweek=first&yday=monday&ymonth2=January&rows_ctr=1&rows_ctr1=1&gid=1

but doing the request again displayed nothing on the header.

Comment: Re chrome: it comes with the browser, hit f12. If you are not seeing the second request then you might not even be reaching the call to send the request. You should set some breakpoints and step through it (in the source tab, click on the left bar as you would on any IDE).

Comment: @magicianIam your exchange with hieu would seem to hint the request does go out. I strongly suggest that you check with fiddler both requests, you can just check the information being in sent in both requests. That alone could tell you what's wrong. If the requests are supposed to have the difference, then it's still very helpful to have the requests in fiddler ready to be re submitted, even to a different server (like your local computer, for debugging). If the requests weren't supposed to have the difference, then you now know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's caching it. Try `cache: false` in the ajax call like so.

```
function setList(str){
    var postDatas = decodeURI($('#form'+str+'').serialize());
    alert(postDatas);
    // $('#crm-feedback').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
    // var formname = "test";
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"admin/page/file.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: postDatas,
        // data: "formname="+formname,
        success: function(data){
            // $('#crm-feedback').html('Saved!').css('color','green');
            alert("test");
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: still wont get trough, also no error on the console or jquery

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're using absolute URLs, some browsers have problems dealing with absolute URLs and treat them as cross-domain requests even if they're not. Check if `base_url+"admin/page/file.php"` is an absolute url (`http://yourserver/admin/page/file.php`). If so, try changing to a relative url.

Comment: what would be a relative url?

Comment: @magicianIam: urls without `http://serverdomain`. For example `/admin/page/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are aware of browser debugging tools and are using them.

If not, for firefox try firebug - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ 
or for chrome, a default developer tool is available. No installations required.
In both cases, press F12 to open the development tool.

If using firebug, click on Net tab. Then do the action to fire your ajax call.
A corresponding line gets added in there. Click on that line. It will open to show some tabs like Headers, Request, Response, etc. 
Look at the response tab. What does it say?

In chrome, there would be a Network tab. Open it and fire your ajax call.
Rest almost similar as in firebug. What does the response tab say.

If you find no conclusive result, try putting breakpoint inside the error function of your ajax call in the script tab in firebug, or sources tab in chrome developer tools. Watch what message the error parameter contains.

Answer (score 0):

Is a .htaccess file involved in serving the page (e.g. pretty urls or some kind of routing)?

If so, try using `http://domain.tld/index.php/page_uri` instead and check if some htaccess rule blocks POST requests.

Are you posting the data to the same URL as the page initiating the AJAX request? If not, a CSRF or Cross-Domain problem might occur. In this case check out [Cross Domain AJAX Guide](http://www.d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/).

Then there could exist a misconfiguration or bug in the php file that should handle the AJAX request. Run PHP-Lint and see what it says or check it by hand.

Actually, you give only little insight into the problem with the data you provided (problem description and code snippet). There may be more problem sources. Like this it's a guessing game. I'm not moaning, see it as a suggestion to update the answer with more information regarding the problem.

Comment: .htaccess is only used for the front end pages not for the backend ones. can you explain this to me http://domain.tld/index.php/page_uri. i am posting the data on the same URL just different file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a random $_GET in your request

```
rand     = rand.getMilliseconds(rand);  
url_ajax ='myajaxpage.php?rand='+rand;  // Force refresh

$.ajax({
    url: url_ajax,
    type: "POST",
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you are using, it could be caching your `POST` request. It isn't jQuery caching so `cache: false` won't help. It is the actual browser.

In `PHP` had to manually set the headers of the response to make sure additional requests to would not be cached.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

Answer (score 0):

You describe an error happening *on the server side*. Please debug your code.

If you have a question about a bug *on the server side*, update your question, or better yet post another question, with the appropriate code (the *server side* code).

---

Make sure your php.ini does not shut off error messages and warnings.

Check your server error log (I imagine you use apache ?).

Comment: that is my server side code, though it now works using chrome only.