# jQuery tab controls placed on bottom don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this solution to have [multiple tabs in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689660/jquery-conflict-with-identical-scripts/3689751#3689751).

```
$(".tab_content").not(':first-child').hide();
var tabs = $('.tabs li');

tabs.filter(':first-child').addClass('active');

tabs.click(function() {
    var current = $(this);

    if(!current.hasClass('active')){
        current.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        var activeTab = current.find("a").attr("href");
        current.parent().next().children().hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }

    return false;
});
```

I need to place the tabs controls after the tab content.
But it won't work. If tabs controls placed before the tabs content, it works fine.
Can you help me?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pivi/pnm98/):

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same id. thats a no-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change next() to prev() - since now the sibling is previous to the tabs

```
current.parent().prev().children().hide().filter(activeTab).fadeIn();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kf2f4/

Comment: ;-) just as simple as that.. thanks a lot, i really appreciate. learned something nice today.